# OpenMP в Code::Blocks

Tags: codeblocks, openmp

Хочу использовать OpenMP в компиляторе Code::Blocks. Компилятор скачал с *http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/binaries*, версию *codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup.exe*. Добавил -fopenmp в Compiler settings -> Other options и -lgomp -pthread в опции линкера. При попытке компиляции примера вылезает ошибка что ld.exe не может найти библиотеку. В MinGW её вроде бы и нету, однако в CB вроде должен же быть gcc, который поддерживает openmp? Можно ли на него как-то переключиться?